# PL/SQL Developer: Change syntax to upper case

Tags: text-editor, plsqldeveloper, textedit

Is there a shortcut and/or command that will highlight syntax and change to upper case?

Example

```
select tablea.id
from  tablea
```

To:

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: In toad do `cntrl + U` to change it to uppercase and `cntrl + L` to lower case

Comment: This has nothing to do with PL/SQL. It is about text editing.

Comment: What tag would you recommend?

Comment: Added the proper tage. For PL/SQL IDE - there isn't a preset shortcut, but you can set it like so: Configure -> Preferences -> Key Configuration -> Scroll down to "Edit / Selection / Uppercase" and "Edit / Selection / Lowercase". I have mapped my shortcuts to Alt + U and Alt + L respectively. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

With version 12.0.7.1837:

Go to Configure tab >> Preferences:

```
User interface >> Editor >> Keyword case >> select 'Uppercase'
```

This will automatically transform *keywords* to uppercase. However, it will not transform schema and table names (I'm not sure if there's a setting for this).

Regarding syntax highlighting, there are a few settings within the same section:

```
User interface >> Editor >> Syntax highlighting
```

Answer (score 2):

Within PL/SQL Developer, go to Tools>Preferences>KeyConfiguration.  Scroll down to Edit/Selection/UpperCase and you can set a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration of case change for SQL Developer Version 4.1.5.21 BUILD MAIN 21.78
Preferences -Code Editor -Completiom Insight
Change case as you type [screen capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqEYC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried `Alt+'` on SQL DEVELOPER Version 20.2.0.175 and it working.